# upon activating ssl, Mixed Content Page: requested an insecure stylesheet error

Tags: wordpress, ssl, plugins

I have two wordpress website and custom plugin that I made to filter products. in one instance of this plugin on this domain name: 
http://klaussongs.com/
The plugin works fine, but when I add it to other domain that has SSL certificate I get mixed content page error. 
https://www.moderndiamondco.com/diamond/
and the plugin also does not work correctly, if I use any filter it just makes all products disappear. 
Here is what's inside my .htaccess file and you could kindly console log the error in the second domain and see the errors: I am using really simple SSL plugin.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

The error only shows when I am logged in at wordpress dashboard so I attach this screenshot for clarity: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I visited that page and the problem right now is: images are loaded via http:// and not with https://

You should check your theme/plugin files if anything like a stylesheet, javascript or image is included with http:// and change it to https://

Right now this image loads with http:

http://www.moderndiamondco.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/path4790-1.png

Change this to https://www.moderndiamondco.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/path4790-1.png

Next: your SSL-certificate is self-signed and invalid. You need to install a valid SSL certificate. (Let`s encrypt or any  paid cert)

And if there are more errors from inside the post contents or customizer-settings in the WP database:

You can solve this problem by installing a search and replace plugin and change all the URLs from

```
http://example.com
```

to

```
https://example.com
```

Here is a guide:

https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003300591-Changing-your-WordPress-database-URLs-to-https-using-a-plugin

Make DB Backups first.

Regards Tom